# Properties of convergent sequences theorem help

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am reviewing some material about sequences and I ran across the following theorem.

*Theorem*: Let $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ be two convergent sequences with limits $x$ and $y$, respectively. Then $(x_n + y_n)$ converges to $x+y$.
The proof that the text uses is as follows.

*Proof:*

Since $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N_1,N_2$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$ for all $n \geq N_1$, $n \geq N_2$, respectively. Taking $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, and with the use of the triangle inequality it follows that 
$$|(x_n+y_n)-(x+y)| \leq |x_n-x| + |y_n-y| \leq 2\epsilon.$$

The question that I have is with the last inequality. If $|x_n-x| + |y_n-y| \leq 2\epsilon$ is true then how does this imply the limit exists?

**Attempt at understanding**

If $|x_n-x| + |y_n-y| \leq 2\epsilon$, then $2\epsilon$ is the largest neighborhood that contains the limit. Thus we can choose another epsilon $\epsilon'\neq\epsilon$ with $\epsilon'<\epsilon$ such that if the limit, in this case $(x+y) \in (x-2\epsilon,x+2\epsilon)$, then $(x+y) \in (x-\frac{\epsilon'}{2},x+\frac{\epsilon'}{2}) \in (x-2\epsilon,x+2\epsilon)$.

Comment: $2\varepsilon$ is not a neighborhood, it's a number...

Comment: I was trying to say that $(x-2\epsilon,x+2\epsilon)$ is the largest neighborhood containing the limit.

Comment: Perhaps to clear the confusion you should start from the definition:

if $x_n \overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}x$, this means (the definition)

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n>N \rightarrow |x_n-x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

which is equally true because you could choose whatever $\epsilon$ you wanted in the first place

Comment: or just relabel $\epsilon' = 2\epsilon$; either is equally valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove it in this way and this proof would stick to  the definition of limit:

---

If $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent, let $\lim_{n->\infty} x_n=L_1$ and $\lim_{n->\infty} y_n=L_2$.

Let $\epsilon$ be any given positive number.
Then for the positive number $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we can find a positive integer $N_1$ such that
$$|x_n-L_1|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}\text{ , for all }n>N_1\text{ ...(1)}$$
Again, for the positive number $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we can find a positive integer $N_2$ such that
$$|y_n-L_2|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}\text{ , for all }n>N_2\text{ ...(2)}$$
Take $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, When $n>N$, both inequalities (1) and (2) hold. Hence
$$|(x_n+y_n)-(L_1+L_2)|=|(x_n-L_1)+(y_n-L_2)|\le |x_n-L_1|+|y_n-L_2|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$for all $n>N$.
Therefore $\lim_{n->\infty}(x_n+y_n)=L_1+L_2$

---

Perhaps this proof would help you understand it because it is derived directly from the definition of limit.

Comment: This was the proof that I first used when I went through the theorem the first time, which makes much more sense to me. However, I was confused on the proof that the text provides.

Comment: May be you can add this sentence at the beginning of your proof: For every $\epsilon_1 \gt 0$. Let $\epsilon_1 =2\epsilon$. Here $\epsilon>0$.($\exists N_1,N_2$........)

Comment: Thank you, that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

$|(x_n+y_n)-(x+y)| \leq |x_n-x| + |y_n-y| \leq 2\epsilon.$

Here $2\epsilon$ is arbitrary. The above inequality tells us that  for any $2\epsilon-$ neighborhood of $(x+y)$, we can find a stage $N\in \Bbb N$ such that all terms of the sequence $(x_n+y_n)$ will lie in this neighborhood.

This is precisely the condition which is required to show that a sequence converges to some point. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is the condition to show that the sequence converges. From this, could we then say for any constant $k$, if $|x_n - x| \leq k\epsilon$, this is enough to prove the sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$?

Comment: Our aim is just to show that for an arbitrary positive number on the RHS of the above inequality we can find a stage after which all terms of a sequence lie in that neighborhood. Since our $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this makes $k\epsilon$  arbitrary where $k$ is some fixed positive number. There is nothing special about $k$, all that matters is that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.